# ByteBuffer vs ChannelBuffer

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, bytebuffer

I am using some framework implemented on the top of netty. I am sending a message from client to server using two options below. I suppose that this two snippets should write same bytes to the socket it behavior at server side is different. How is it different?

Option 1: okay

```
ChannelBuffer buf = ChannelBuffers.buffer(1);
buf.writeByte(0x1c);
e.getChannel().write(buf);
```

Option 2: fails

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
buf.put(0x1c);
e.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(buf));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you can write the ByteBuffer to the Channel you have to call

```
buf.flip();
```

This is making the bytes visible for write.

Comment: yeah, now it produces the same result. where can I read more about the nature of this issue. thanks!

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov A simple explanation you can find in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip())